# What would happen if I configured a local file system for Flink checkpointing?

Tags: apache-flink, flink-streaming, checkpointing

I have saw a video named `Managing State in Apache Flink - Tzu-Li (Gordon) Tai`.
In this [video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=euFMWFDThiE), it stores data with distributed file system.

I'm wondering that what would happen if I configured a local file system for Flink checkpointing?

eg:

```
env.setStateBackend(new RocksDBStateBackend(getString("flie:///tmp/checkpoints"), true));
```

I assume that every node of Flink cluster will keep their own data. Would it work well?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I assume that every node of Flink cluster will keep their own data.

That is correct.

> Would it work well?

With a local file system and distributed nodes you would may be able to checkpoint just fine (even that is not certain, as the directory may be getting created by the `JobManager` so the `TaskManager` instances potentially will fail with the directory not existing) however you would not be able to restore, as the `JobManager` reads that and distributes that out to the operators as needed.

Strictly speaking, it does not matter if the file system is local or distributed to `flink`. What is important is that the `JobManager` as restore time is able to see all of the checkpoint data. If you are running with everything on the same machine, then a local file system would work just fine.

I think in principle you could even have all nodes write locally and then manually use a synchronization process to move the data to somewhere that the `JobManager` could see it during an attempted restore, however that is certainly not a recommended approach.